# *** caught segfault *** address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped' in R MAXENT Text Classification

Tags: r, classification, text-mining

I'm using the *maxent* R package on *R.3.2.1* for supervised classification and training of 1,000,000 tweets holding out 25% for testing.  where `Tweet` is the predictor variable and `City` is the label. The Linux kernel runs on a Centos clustered platform with a minimum of 128GB RAM per core. Memory's not an issue.

Here's my R code:

```
library(maxent)
file <- read.csv("JoinedTable.csv")
data <- file[sample(1:3700000,size=1000000,replace=FALSE),]
matrix <- create_matrix(data$Tweet, language="english", stripWhitespace = TRUE, toLower = TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, removePunctuation = TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)
sparse2 <- as.compressed.matrix(matrix)
model <- maxent(sparse2[1:750000,],as.factor(data$CIty)[1:750000])
results <- predict(model,sparse2[750001:1000000,])
```

And here's the error message returned:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .External(list(name = "InternalFunction_invoke", address = <pointer: 0x2a3d5750>,     dll = list(name = "Rcpp", path = "/users/40113951/gridware/share/R/3.2.1/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so",         dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: 0x451c3e90>,         info = <pointer: 0x7fe0c5ecb940>), numParameters = -1L),     <pointer: 0x42b1aea0>, ...)
 2: maximumentropy$classify_samples(as.integer(feature_matrix@dimension[1]),     as.integer(feature_matrix@dimension[2]), feature_matrix@ia,     ja, feature_matrix@ra, model)
 3: classify_maxent(feature_matrix, object@model)
 4: predict.maxent(model, sparse2[750001:1e+06, ])
 5: predict(model, sparse2[750001:1e+06, ])

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Comment: Inform the authors of the package and try to reproduce the error on a smaller dataset. It looks like a bug, don't think anybody but the authors could help here.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the source of the error, it was due to a typo in line 6 of the code; predictor variable was written as `CIty` instead of `City`

However, this has led to another error message. I have informed the package  maintainer but no response received on this. Does this mean that the MAXENT package cannot handle more than 255 unique labels. Read the documentation [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj49Peu9OHMAhVHYyYKHdzpDmsQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fmaxent%2Fmaxent.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG1FAPtII59B8XhJBzKKGDNEs8ZRw&sig2=6hRjI3DfoSwYUiSV6p3f_Q) no such mention about restrictions on number of labels

`[1] "ERROR: Too many types of labels (>255 unique labels)."`